# php echo ommitting <form> on first iteration

Tags: php

**EDIT: The problem has been fixed, prior parts in the code were formatted wrongly**

I am writing a search results page for an online shopping website, and I am facing a problem.

Below is the code for an iteration of the echo after an extract from my database:

```
$count=1;
while($prod=$gettingprods->fetch_assoc()){
    echo"<div style='text-align:center;margin-left:10px;width:350px;height:225px;display:inline-block;float:left;border-radius:7px;border-color:red;border-style:inset;margin-bottom:10px'>
    <h5>".$prod['brand_name']." ".$prod['product_name']."</h5>
    <h6>Chez ".$prod['shop_name']."</h6>
    <h5 style='font-color:red'>Prix Unitaire LBP/USD: ".$prod['pis_lbp']."/".sprintf('%.2f',$prod['pis_usd'])."</h5>
    <form action='addtocart.php?val=".$count."' id='prod".$count."' method='post'>
    <p><input type='number' name='qty".$count."' min='1' placeholder='Quantité'/></p>
    <p><div id='buttonNext' name='add".$count."' onclick='submitForm".$count."()'>
Ajouter
</div></p>
    <input type='hidden' name='url".$count."' 
value='".substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)."'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='prod".$count."' value=".$prod['pis_id'].">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
  function submitForm".$count."(){
      document.getElementById('prod".$count."').submit();
  }
  </script>";
  $count+=1;
}
```

While I have no problem displaying the desired result, the form does not let me submit the FIRST product displaying, regardless of product. In the console, it is giving me the following statement, whenever I try to submit that form:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
at submitForm1 (searchresults.php?type=shop&query=3:99)
at HTMLDivElement.onclick (searchresults.php?type=shop&query=3:90)
```

The problem is only happening with the first div, attached below is a sample screenshot of how the page looks like:
http://prntscr.com/glgqgh

Any help would be appreciated. Note that security doesn't matter at that point. Thanks

EDIT: here is a sample output code from the inspector:

```
<div style="text-align:center;margin-
left:10px;width:350px;height:225px;display:inline-block;float:left;border-
radius:7px;border-color:red;border-style:inset;margin-bottom:10px">
    <h5>Al Wadi Al Akhdar Sweet Corn</h5>
    <h6>Chez Supermarché Test</h6>
    <h5 style="font-color:red">Prix Unitaire LBP/USD: 1500/1.00</h5>

    <p><input type="number" name="qty1" min="1" placeholder="Quantité"></p>
    <p></p><div id="buttonNext" name="add1" onclick="submitForm1()">
Ajouter
</div><p></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="url1" value="searchresults.php?type=shop&amp;query=3">
    <input type="hidden" name="prod1" value="4">

  </div>
<script>
function submitForm1(){
  document.getElementById('prod1').submit();
}
</script>
```

As far as I can see, there wasn't a  outputted for this one, can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are repeating the submit function for each form?

try to make one function for all forms, try this:

php:

```
$count=1;
while($prod=$gettingprods->fetch_assoc()){
    echo
    "<div style='text-align:center;margin-left:10px;width:350px;height:225px;display:inline-block;float:left;border-radius:7px;border-color:red;border-style:inset;margin-bottom:10px'>
        <h5>".$prod['brand_name']." ".$prod['product_name']."</h5>
        <h6>Chez ".$prod['shop_name']."</h6>
        <h5 style='font-color:red'>Prix Unitaire LBP/USD: ".$prod['pis_lbp']."/".sprintf('%.2f',$prod['pis_usd'])."</h5>
        <form action='addtocart.php?val=".$count."' id='prod".$count."' method='post'>
            <p><input type='number' name='qty".$count."' min='1' placeholder='Quantité'/></p>
            <p>
                <div id='buttonNext' name='add".$count."' onclick='submitForm(".$count.")'>
                    Ajouter
                </div>
            </p>
            <input type='hidden' name='url".$count."' value='".substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)."'/>
            <input type='hidden' name='prod".$count."' value=".$prod['pis_id'].">
        </form>
    </div>";
    $count+=1;
}
```

js:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(count){
        document.getElementById('prod'+count).submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried it. Thanks for the heads up. Any clue though on why the first <form> in the loop isn't echoing while the others are?

Comment: @RabihMelko is the shared html right? so there is no `<form>` tag for the first prod?

Comment: well it is shared in the way that I am printing it for each iteration, but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @RabihMelko look at ur html, there is no `<form>` tag

Comment: yes in the first there isn't any form tag, yet with the others there is. Also in Sources there is form even on the first one